# Python what is the pythonic way of comparing 2 increasing in size lists?

Tags: python, list

I have one list (list a) that increases based on size and has items removed from this list and put into another list (list b) that maintains what has already been checked.

The list that is maintaining (list b) what has been done needs to be compared with the list that has content (list a) that hasn't been checked already; what is the most efficient way to do this check in python? **Even when the contents of each list can go well over 10k items.**

```
while listA:
    for a in listA:
        #do something

        listB.append(url)
        listA.remove(url)
```

This is the furthest I can get.

Comment: I can't really understand your question, but maybe "list b" should be a `set`

Comment: I'm kind of confused on how to exactly "compare" two lists in python in a loop until listA is no longer iterable

Comment: Your code will produce inconsistent output. You shouldn't iterate and modify a list in the same loop context.

Comment: @msalvadores what would you suggest to be best approach? I also need to check each individual item in the list so I need to be able to go over the list.

Comment: @thatguy Have a look at my answer and see if it gives you some ideas.

Comment: Is there any reason to modify listA? Why not simply iterate over it?

Comment: @Artisiom it is a dynamic list

Comment: Sorry if i miss something - but what do you mean on dynamic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code will produce inconsistent output. You shouldn't iterate and modify a list in the same loop context.

You could use `listA` as a `Queue`:

```
 while len(listA):
     element = listA.pop()
     #do something with element
     listB.add(element)
```

this code is consistent because even tough the list is being modified within the while loop there is no iterator created for `listA`. Only the len of the list is checked to make sure that the program terminates.

Comment: definitely has improved my results dramatically. Now what about comparing a dynamic list with a dynamic list?

Comment: That seems like a different problem, post it as a different question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really need. To compare unique values from two lists you can try to use [set data type](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
a = xrange(11000)
b = xrange(0,11000,10)
diff = set(a).difference(set(b))
inter = set(a).intersection(set(b))
```

Also you can try to take a look at the [difference_update](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=difference#set.difference_update) that:

> Update the set, removing elements
>   found in others.